# russian keyboard ubuntu shows english text

Tags: input-language

I switched to Russian keyboard, but when I type it still displays English words. 
I tried this solution https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
but this does not seem to work.

How to change source input to Russian?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu for many years and never met this problem. It is very unclear what happened. If you install Russian keyboard layout, you can always switch to Russian or English by hotkeys or language selector.

Comment: I already changed to to Russian language input but it still prints English words

Comment: How did you change to Russian?

Comment: as described here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: It it is described how to INSTALL Russian layout, but that doesn't immidiately switches to Russian. Hotkey depends on your system, Default is Alt+Shift, or Super+Space. You can also switch by mouse on top of your screen.

Comment: at the top app bar it says that changed to "ru"

Comment: Then something is wrong with your system. It is impossible to guess. Try to reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only needed to tap apt-get update and reboot. it resolved all the problems.